# hide url path from address bar

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way (using JavaScript, PHP or HTML) to hide the URL from address bar?

For example I have:

```
www.mysite.it/public/network.php
```

and I want only

```
www.mysite.it/public/ or www.mysite.it/public/#
```

My site is written in PHP.

Comment: Whhhhyyyyyyy!!! You don't like `clean url`, like `www.mysite.com/public/network`? It looks neat though.

Comment: Hmm.. Just wanna point you in a right direction.. Hopefully, try to check this one. http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls or http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/

Comment: it's hard to ask proper question :) you need to use url rewriting check apache mod_rewrite or any other module for webserver that you use

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way (using javascript , php or html) to hide url path from
>   address bar?

No, but you can create .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^public/$ public/network.php [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't hide the path, it changes the path that the document is available at.

Comment: @Quentin I know. But it's the closest solution.

Answer (score 0):

No. At least, nothing sensible. (You can play around with `pushState` and friends, but that would be a horrible abuse).

If you want the URL to show `www.mysite.it/public/` then set up your server so that is the URL of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You accomplish this with module rewrite.  That will allow you to alter the URL, or rather how to server perceives the URL.

Then using .htaccess, you can make an internal rewrite, just as: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess

In that example, the base directory rewrites the url internally to `app.php`, effectively replacing the default behavior apache sending the request to `index.php`.